# Styled-system in react native using stylesheet

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, native, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to make stylesheet in react native able to use dynamic value, but i have no idea how to declare it, and can we change the styling name of react native style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a stylesheet in react native in this way

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {


return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>welcome</Text>
  </View>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   paddingTop: 10,
   backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
   padding: 8,
 },
 welcomeText:{
   color:'red',
 },
 });
```

Read about this in the documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet).